# Enable HTTPS for accessing the Portainer WebUI

Tags: https, portainer

I created an A record for accessing the Portaner Web UI by using a domain name instead of the IP address. So the Web UI URL looks like http://por.example.com:9000. But how can I enable HTTPS so that the Web UI can be accessed using https://por.example.com:9000? Please shed some lights. Thanks!

BTW, the Portainer is installed to my Ubuntu server running on Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 0):

The A record is used to resolve to the host (`por.example.com`) not the protocol (http vs https). Have a look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) to understand the different parts of a URL.

So your issue has nothing to do with whether you enter the URL as http://por.example.com:9000 or http://192.168.1.22:9000, it has to do with configuring Portainer to accept HTTPS requests on port 9000.

When I install Portainer, this is the default setup - although by default it lacks a valid SSL certificate, so you need to click 'Advanced' then 'Proceed' in chrome to see the Portainer Web UI.